# ok http to only time out when no data has been sent or recieved for some time

Tags: java, okhttp

Is it possible to configure okhttp to timeout only when no reads or writes have occurred in the last X seconds.

The case I have is I wish to either upload a large file or download a large file however if the read/write timeouts are lower than the total amount of time it takes to upload/download a timeout occurs.

For example:

```
read timeout = 5 seconds
write timeout = 5 seconds
We upload 100MB every second, and the file to upload is 2GB so it takes 20 seconds to upload.
```

This results in a read timeout as it times out waiting on the read even though bytes are still being sent to the sever.

Is it possible to only throw timeout exceptions when nothing has been transferred for 5 seconds that way the exception is thrown when the upload stops.

Here is a sample of the client:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client = client.newBuilder()
    .readTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
    .writeTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(1000000))
    .sslSocketFactory(/** conscrypt and trust store set */)
    .hostnameVerifier(/** my host name verifier */)
    .build();


Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(serverRoot)
      .put(RequestBody.create(new byte[SlowUploadTestServlet.MB_TO_SEND*1024*1024]))
      .build();

try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
    System.out.println(response.body().string());
}
```

and the response:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
    at okio.SocketAsyncTimeout.newTimeoutException(Okio.kt:149)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout.access$newTimeoutException(AsyncTimeout.kt:162)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$source$1.read(AsyncTimeout.kt:340)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.kt:449)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.kt:333)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.kt:105)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec$ChunkedSource.readChunkSize(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:444)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec$ChunkedSource.read(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:426)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange$ResponseBodySource.read(Exchange.kt:276)
    at okio.Buffer.writeAll(Buffer.kt:1655)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readString(RealBufferedSource.kt:95)
    at okhttp3.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.kt:187)
    at com.funnelback.api.core.DefaultRestTimeoutIT.lambda$12(DefaultRestTimeoutIT.java:276)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: socket is closed
    at org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket$SSLInputStream.read(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:552)
    at okio.InputStreamSource.read(Okio.kt:93)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$source$1.read(AsyncTimeout.kt:129)
    ... 35 more
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the 5 second read timeout is triggering? It's documented to trigger only if a read is attempted and no bytes are returned within the specified duration.

Comment: https://square.github.io/okio/2.x/okio/okio/-timeout/

Comment: @JesseWilson I attached the client an exception, I can confirm it is a read timeout on the client even though the server is still accepting data sent to it